# How do I pull out values from a row in a gridview from a onclick event?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, onclick

I have a datatable that I bind to a gridview to display on screen. I have some buttons in each row of the gridview and when it gets displayed on screen I can click on the button in the row and there is a onclick event being called. In the onclick event I want to pull out the other values from that row so that I can do stuff with them. How would I do that?
e.g. if I select the button in the 3rd row down, I want to pull all the values from the 3rd row.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
  Dim btnClicked As Button = CType(sender, Button)
  Dim gvRow As GridViewRow = CType(btnClicked.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
```

Using the gvRow, you can find the other controls in that row to obtain values.

Please mark this as an answer if I answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your button click event handler use following code:

```
GridViewRow row = (GridviewRow)((Button)sender).NamingContainer;
TextBox txt = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtMyText");
Label lbl = (Label)row.FindControl("lblMyLabel");
string txtval = txt.Text;
string lblval = lbl.Text;

// or using cells of the row

string value1 = row.Cells[0].Value;
string value2 = row.Cells[1].Value;
```